# Getting minimum values of mappings

Tags: haskell

I want to get the minimum values from two mappings and subtract one from the other. I'm really new to Haskell and am pretty embarrassed by my attempt but I wanted to give it a go before asking!

```
    calc :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> Float
    calc = a - b
         where
         a = minimum map1
         b = minimum map2
    map1 f xs = [f x | x <- xs]
    map2 f xs = [square x | x <- xs]
    square x = x*x
```

I'm getting so many errors that I feel like I must be doing it completely the wrong way?

Comment: [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) comes highly recommended for beginners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that `map2` just discards the function it's given. `map1` is just the standard `map` function, so you don't need to define it. `map2` can be defined properly as:

```
map2 = map square
```

The second problem is that you haven't supplied `map1` and `map2` with any arguments in your definition of `calc`. Is something like this what you want?

```
calc :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> Float
calc f xs = a - b
     where
     a = minimum (map f xs)
     b = minimum (map2 xs)
```

Basically, your problem is that you're declaring parameters but not processing them, or using functions that take parameters without actually specifying them. That doesn't work in any language :)

That's not all, however. Your type for `calc` is wrong. I suggest you think about *why* this can't work — in particular, what if I say *a* is `String` and *b* is `()`? You can try removing the type signature of `calc` and entering `:t calc` into GHCi to find out what the type GHC infers for `calc` is to get a head-start on correcting it.

Comment: thanks! feeling pretty stupid but i guess we all have to start somewhere!